# How do I inherit controls in other form in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb6-migration

I'm converting our old program written in VB6 to C# WPF, and there is this code that I'm having a hard time trying to convert.

In our old VB6 project. The code is written like this:

```
Select Case paymentType
  Case "CASH":
      Set dlgpayment = New dlgPaymentCash
      dlgPaymentCash.lblChange = format(-gvAmountDue - gvAddOnAmount, "0.00")   '/NJ-2011/10/25 Added gvAddOnAmount
  Case "CARD":  
      If PaymentTypeSupports(gvPaymentType, "multiple") And PaymentTypeSupports(gvPaymentType, "remember") And TypeName(dlgpayment) = "dlgPaymentCreditCard" Then

      Else
          Set dlgpayment = New dlgPaymentCreditCard
      End If
```

`dlgPayment` is declared as:

```
Window dlgPayment = new Window();
```

so whenever I want to inherit other windows, I will just simply code like this:

```
Set dlgPayment = new dlgPaymentCash //dlgPaymentCash is a form.
```

And whenever I do this, I was able to access the controls in the form `dlgPaymentCreditCard` like `dlgPaymentCash.lblChange`, but it doesn't work in C#.

Comment: that's not C#, that's VB

Comment: Thanks for the comment. That code is the code im trying to convert using C# and i can't seem to find a way to convert it.

Comment: @Jonesopolis The OP made it quite clear that it _was_ VB6

Comment: you're right @MickyD, that's my bad

Answer (score 1):

This is roughly the conversion:

```
switch (paymentType) {
  case "CASH":
    var dlgpayment = new dlgPaymentCash();
    dlgPaymentCash.lblChange = string.Format("{0:0.00}", -gvAmountDue - gvAddOnAmount);
    //NJ-2011/10/25 Added gvAddOnAmount
    break;
  case "CARD":
    if (PaymentTypeSupports(gvPaymentType, "multiple")
     && PaymentTypeSupports(gvPaymentType, "remember")
     && typeof(dlgpayment) == "dlgPaymentCreditCard") {
      //.....
    } else {
      var dlgpayment = new dlgPaymentCreditCard();
    }
    break;
}
```

If the `format()` function is the standard VB6 one, you can either use the `string.Format()` function, or simply the `.ToString()` function.

Comment: Your `string.Format` isn't right, you have the things reversed, should be `string.Format("{0:0.00}", -gvAmountDue - gvAddOnAmount);`

Answer (score 0):

You can access a variable inside a Window by callling WindowName.VariableName like this:

```
switch(paymentType)
{
    case "CASH":
                    Window dlgPayment = new Window();
                    //Access variable lblChange in dlgPayment
                    dlgPayment.lblChange="something";
                    break;
    case "CARD":
                    break;
    default:
                    break;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i cannot access the variable lblchange using the dlgPayment. I can make code like. dlgPayment.Show(); and it will display the form. But whenever it doesnt work anymore whenever i try to access objects.

Comment: did you set the variable inside dlgPayment is "public"? Why is it reject you from accessing? Any error/warning?

Comment: Yes. the variable is set in "public" i also change the modifiers to "public" but still, it doesn't let the dlgPayment to access the objects inside the form.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you create a class which inherited the Window class (Which represent the form) :

in xaml.cs

```
public partial class PaymentDialog : Window //inherit Window
{
    public string lblChange {get;set;} //this should be a textblock/label in xaml, but i just assume it is a string.

}
```

You need to create instance of  PaymentDialog by:

```
PaymentDialog dlgPayment = new PaymentDialog(); //notice the different
dlgPayment.lblChange = "XXX"; //you now can access it

Window dlgPaymentWindow = new Window();
dlgPaymentWindow.lblChange = "XXX";//you cannot access it since 
//lblChange is not exist in WPF Window class
```